# Android Studio 1.1.0 You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendent) crush

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, themes

Using:
Android Studio 1.1.0
API 21 (Android 5.0.1)

Crush exception:

```
04-09 19:06:59.089    1892-1892/com.example.abrate.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.abrate.myapplication, PID: 1892
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abrate.myapplication/com.example.abrate.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:152)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:149)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
        at com.example.abrate.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.abrate.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.abrate.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I don't know how to fix the issue, I would like to use Theme.Holo.Light for my application and in the android developers site (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) it is written that if your API is 11 or HIGHER the mainactivity.java should import "android.app.ActionBar" and not "android.support.v7.app.ActionBar", so how to fix the issue? Should I go ahead using Theme.AppCompat or trying to solve the problem and use "android.app.ActionBar" and Theme.Holo?

Answer (score 2):

this `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"` in your manifest needs to be `AppCompat`

> it is written that if your API is 11 or HIGHER the mainactivity.java should import "android.app.ActionBar" and not "android.support.v7.app.ActionBar"

this was the case (but not a requirement as there are cases where this is not possible) when all you had was the `Holo` theme but now there is the `Material` theme

Comment: Sorry but I don't see the point... Why is Android Studio importing android.support.v7.app.ActionBar if the API I'm using is 21?

Comment: If you are only supporting api 21 then yes in most cases you can just use normal activity however like I said there are cases where you have no choice but to use the support activity. If you are providing backwards compatibility for api 21 then yes you should be using the support activity

Comment: But if I use the Base.Theme.AppCompat.whatever, the icon in the action bar is not shown, in stead of the Holo.Light, any solutions?

manifest.xml
    `<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" >`

Comment: if you are using api 21 you should be using the `Theme.Material` and using `Toolbar` and NOT `Actionbar`  http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html